# Quitting while bosses are out of town

Tags: quitting

I am the only employee at a new company that is ran by a married couple. The environment is incredibly abusive and I have decided to leave at this time because I have just started on a brand new project that will take years to develop. I am the only person on this project, and I think it is best I quit now before I waste too much time on it (and the company's money). I have two questions:

1) My bosses are out of town until next week, and there is obviously no HR department to give notice to. Is it better to let them know of my resignation as soon as possible by email or should I wait until they return to do it in person?

2) In this situation I don't feel that it makes much sense to give two weeks notice as there is no one for me to train or hand my project off to, and I know they will not be hiring a replacement for a long time. In addition, my health is really suffering from being in this environment and I would like to get out as soon as possible. Should I still offer two weeks notice?

Comment: Where in the world are you? From the fact that you think we know exactly how giving notice in your country works, I'll take a guess and say USA?

Comment: Yes I am in the US, sorry about that confusion.

Comment: Note: OP is also asking *Should I still offer two weeks notice?*

Comment: @Physika - the fact that they are out of town is a non-issue.  Send a short email and you're done.  Good luck with your new career!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give notice in person when you can, by email when you have to. In this case they're out of town, so an email will have to do. Be prepared for a phone call too.

The standard notice period (two weeks in your case) should normally be given, but you can *ask* to reduce it - something like "I understand that in giving my notice my last day should be X, but under the circumstances I would like to discuss the possibility of an earlier departure, on a date on which we can both agree". If your health is suffering, though, the normal conventions may not apply - no job is worth sacrificing your health for, least of all one where you're leaving anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Who do you report to in their absence?   If you have to call in sick...who do you call?   That's the person.

Maybe you don't have anyone.  In that case, I'd email them.    They will probably be checking their email.

Personally, I always like to give 2 weeks notice and not burn bridges if I can help it, but it sounds like this isn't a situation where you can do that.

Comment: From the description of the environment, perhaps the OP does want to burn those bridges...

Comment: The company should have an official address. Mail delivered to that official address will do. Use registered mail. It's legally delivered when the postman knocks on the door, even it nobody answers and he takes the letter back to the post office.